Why is redirect not working in Production build. NextJS14
I'm triying to authenticate through the production build of my project. However, I found out that there's an issue with redirect().
I initially though it was a server error on my ExpressJS backend but I checked the logs and the POST request is succesful, however, the front end is not setting up cookies as it should and thus redirect fails.
import {
  fetchurl,
  setAuthTokenOnServer,
  setUserOnServer,
} from '@/helpers/setTokenOnServer'
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
import FormButtons from '@/components/global/formbuttons'

const Login = async ({ params, searchParams }) => {

  const loginAccount = async (formData) => {
    'use server'
    const rawFormData = {
      email: formData.get('email'),
      password: formData.get('password')
    }

    const res = await fetchurl(`/auth/login`, 'POST', 'no-cache', rawFormData);

    if (res?.data) {
      redirect(`/auth/validatetwofactorauth/${res?.data?._id}`)
    }

    // If not success, stop
    if (!res?.success) return;
    
    await setAuthTokenOnServer(res?.token); // Sets auth cookies on server
    const loadUser = await fetchurl(`/auth/me`, 'GET', 'no-cache'); // loads user based on auth
    await setUserOnServer(loadUser?.data); // then sets some user's values into cookies
    searchParams?.returnpage ? redirect(searchParams.returnpage) : redirect(`/auth/profile`);
  }

  return (
    <form action={loginAccount}>
      <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">
        Email
      </label>
      <input
        id="email"
        name="email"
        type="email"
        className="form-control mb-3"
        placeholder="john@doe.com"
      />
      <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">
        Password
      </label>
      <input
        id="password"
        name="password"
        type="password"
        className="form-control mb-3"
        placeholder="******"
      />
      <br />
      <FormButtons />
    </form>
  )
}

export default Login

Anyone has dealt with this before? I'd like to keep the page in the server side as much as possible.
Click here to see local vs production build examples
Thanks in advance!.

Hey, can you make sure there's a shared root layout as suggested https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/58263#issuecomment-1974306356 in the production build?

Yeah, it does have root layout
